# Invoking a class method by jQuery AJAX: Avoid creation of .php file just to host call to the method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oop

Instead of having to specify the jQuery AJAX url: "" with a page (and parameters) for each class method I'd like to call, are there any options to directly invoke a class method (as described below).

Before my form an object (and the mapper) are instantiated:

```
$entry = new Entry();
$entryMapper = new EntryMapper(pdo-conn-goes-here);
```

Then I want to call an $entryMapper method (specifically the one that saves to the database):

```
$entryMapper->saveEntry();
```

As I understand it, I need to have a URL that leads to a page which calls/runs my method. Since there will be many such calls in my app, I'm wondering what is the common way (best practice) for such a situation? Isn't there any way to circumvent creation of such files just to host/call/invoke desired methods? Of course, I can have a single file with conditional statements but I don't see that being useful either.

Comment: Why do you want to circumvent good design?

Comment: I feel the other way is a better design. I see no point in creation new files just to have them call existing methods in existing classes.
So, is your solution to have a single file with conditional statements which I would refer anytime I need to AJAX-call one of the methods inside it?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the Front Controller pattern.  Building a single entry point to control object instantiation, method calls, session handling, exception handling etc can be very advantageous.

Comment: Oh well, at least with this I was able to move some business logic to the ajaxcalls.php (namely, class imports and instantiation of object and saveEntry($entry) method.
But now the path to my ajaxcalls.php file is visible in the source code. How can this be avoided?

Comment: @JonathanSpiller FYI, my previous comment has nothing to do with your last comment (we were probably typing them at the same time but yours seem to be added first). I heard of Front Controller pattern and will look into it, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, it doesn't matter if the path to ajaxcalls.php is visible in the source code. Try make it a relative path, not absolute, and most importantly, make sure to check for a valid session first thing in ajaxcalls.php.

Comment: It is relative but since my page is in the root, it's easy to conclude where ajax file is. Anyway, could you briefly elaborate on how would I be able to achieve some kind of a direct invocation of my class method if I implement the FC pattern, as opposed to the current working solution?